# Why does my Go web server return "404 page not found" when run inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, go, containers, webserver

I'm building a small, basic web server in Go. If I compile locally and run it, it works great - no issues. The pages show, it's accessible from the localhost, styling intact - all good.

If I then do it inside a Docker container, it doesn't work. It returns "404 page not found". It's like it doesn't have any of the static assets... but this surely can't be - the static assets are intentionally embedded in to the binary using "//go:embed"... and as I said, if you build and run locally it works fine.

I've tried everything I can think of... some steps listed below:

1. Various different docker images (alpine, ubuntu, golang, golang alpine etc)
2. Using go:embed in different ways i.e. different patterns
3. I put some basic logging in to the server code... but it doesn't seem to return any errors so hasn't helped
4. Changed ports/address

This is just some of the stuff I've tried, with no luck.

I've excluded the css below, it's not really relevant as the index page doesn't even show never mind any styling.

CODE: [server code](https://pastebin.com/a0htp8hC)

DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM golang:1.16.0-alpine3.13 AS build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go build -o server .

FROM golang:1.16.0-alpine3.13

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build /app/server .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["./server"]
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>GOOO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>GO!!!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

DIRECTORY STRUCTURE:

```sh
├── Dockerfile
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── server.go
├── server_test.go
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── index.html
```

Comment: What url are you testing when you get the 404 back? Your code is still serving `index.html` from the filesystem (`http.ServeFile(w, r, "./static/index.html")`) so I would expect that to fail.

Comment: You need to copy your `static` assets to the final stage of your Docker build.

Comment: Hi @Brits

When I test locally, I'm using "localhost:8080" which works. It doesn't work when it's run inside Docker though.

How can I serve the file from the embedded filesystem instead? So that I don't need to copy the static files anywhere.

Comment: @SamWood you could use this https://github.com/markbates/pkger to package the static files into the binary

Comment: @SamuelTJackson Go version 1.16 handles the embedding of files in to the binary - in this case I'm just having issues trying to serve them. I'm doing something wrong... I just don't know what it is yet.

Comment: @SamWood as per my earlier comment you are serving `index.html` from the filesystem (and it will not be found) - either copy it into your docker image or serve it from the embedded filesystem. You will also need to use something like `s, err := fs.Sub(static, "static")`  because the static filesystem root fill be `/static/`. Note: No need to test embed in docker; just run your executable from another folder (so the `/static` folder is not found) - this may make it easier to debug.

Comment: @Brits I understand now what the issue is, but not how to solve it. I think you've given fragments of a solution, but I can't really see how it fits together. How can I make it serve the file from my embedded filesystem? The http.ServeFile() simply takes a string argument for the name of the file, nothing to specify where the file is. Is there another, more appropriate method to use? I've had a look through the http package, but nothing sticks out to me. I'm trying to avoid copying the static assets in to the final docker image, really want it to use only the embedded files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments the main issue you are having is that you are serving `index.html` from the file system (not the embedded filesystem) and the file does not exist there.

A second issue is that the embedded filesystem will contain a single directory `static` so you need to use something like `s, err := fs.Sub(static, "static")` so that `s.Open("index.html")` will work (otherwise you would need `static.Open("static/index.html")` - this applies to your `http.FileServer` as well as when serving index.html).

Note: You may not need the below because you could just run `http.FileServer` for the `/` path (so it serves `index.html` and the files in the subdirectories). `http.FileServer`  will automatically serve `index.html` if no filename is provided in the url.

To serve `index.html` from the embedded filesystem you could rewrite your function as (untested!):

```
// default/root handler which serves the index page and associated styling
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    f, err := s.Open("index.html") // Using `s` from above and assumes its global; better to use handlerfunc and pass filesystem in

    if err != nil {
        // Send whatever error you want (as file is embedded open should never fail)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    if _, err := io.Copy(w, f); err != nil { // Write out the file
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

The above relies upon a global variable (which I'm not keen on) so I'd transform this into something like:

```
func IndexHandlerFunc(fs fs.FS, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        f, err := fs.Open("index.html")

        if err != nil {
            // Send whatever error you want (as file is embedded open should never fail)
            return
        }
        defer f.Close()

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
        if _, err := io.Copy(w, f); err != nil { // Write out the file
            // Handle error
        }
    })
}
```